# RDP file options for Windows 10

Tags: windows, rdp

I am trying to figure out how to enable "multitransport" from a RDP file but for the life of me I cannot find RDP 8.1 options documented anywhere.  I found something for Windows 2008 r2 (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393699(v=ws.10).aspx).  This just gives options for RDP 7.x nothing for RDP 8.x.  Has anyone run into this?

Comment: What options are you trying to set?  I thought this was more or less [negotiated and enabled automatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872141.aspx) when both sides supported it.

Comment: I am using xfreerdp and I want to explicitly enable the multitransport feature.

Comment: Seems like you should be looking in the xfreerdp source to see if this even an option.  Maybe ask on the xfreerdp maillist.